# python - how do I expand and save my graphs?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want my graphs expanded and saved. Tried to do it in my codes and not sure if bbox_inches='tight' is doing what it needs to do, as my graph looks very small and the there seems to be a lot of space between the graph and the edge.

Below I have show snap of how the code is saving and how it looks if I manually expand and save the graph. How do I fix it?

fyi its not same as changing the size of the figures so (as someone suggested it to be and closed the question!)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for x in range(3):
    yy = np.random.randint(1,10,100)
    plt.plot(yy)
    plt.savefig('filename' + str(x) + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.figure()

plt.show()
```

[image: saved by the code]

[image: manually saved]